# c++: vector does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

very easy but frustrating question from me.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector <int> queue;

queue.push_back(2);

int main(){
    cout << queue[0] <<endl;
}
```

compiled with g++ -std=c++11 Cpp_test.cpp, return error

```
Cpp_test.cpp:51:1: error: ‘queue’ does not name a type
 queue.push_back(2);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't notice that i have written outside of main. It is not relevant to vector type.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but with that `using namespace std;` you run the risk that the compiler will also see `std::queue` in the global namespace and get confused about whether `queue` is the name of that template or the name of your object. Get rid of `using namespace std;`. Namespaces exist for a reason, and blowing them away will burn you eventually.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`queue.push_back(2);` should go in main.

To clarify, you cant just place code arbitrarily and have it executed. Declarations are fine outside of main, but that's not a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Jay is correct. However, since you're using C++11, you can keep your "initialisation" near the declaration by actually making it an initialisation:

```
vector<int> queue = {2};
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e5304ce1d6ba2a3))

By the way, `std::vector` is a strange choice for a queue.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually trying out sort function. Didn' notice that i have write codes outside main.